# How to make json-schema to allow one but not another field?

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

Is it possible to make `jsonschema` to have only one of two fields.

For example, image if I want to have a `JSON` with ether `start_dt` or `end_dt` but not both of them at the same time. like this:

#### OK

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "start_dt": "2012-10-10"
}
```

#### OK

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "end_dt": "2012-10-10"
}
```

#### NOT OK

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "start_dt": "2012-10-10"
    "end_dt": "2013-11-11"
}
```

What should I add to the schema:

```
{ 
    "title": "Request Schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": 
            {   
                "type": "string"
            },  
        "start_dt": 
            {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date"

            },
        "end_dt":
            {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date"
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can express this using `oneOf`.  This means that the data must match *exactly one* of the supplied sub-schemas, but not more than one.

Combining this with `required`, this schema says that instances must either define `start_dt`, OR define `end_dt` - but if they contain both, then it is invalid:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {"type": "string"},
        "start_dt": {"type": "string", "format": "date"},
        "end_dt": {"type": "string", "format": "date"}
    },
    "oneOf": [
        {"required": ["start_dt"]},
        {"required": ["end_dt"]}
    ]
}
```

Online demos with your three examples:

- [OK](http://geraintluff.github.io/tv4/try/#?data=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22start_dt%22%3A%20%222012-10-10%22%0A%7D%20&schema=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22object%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22properties%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%7B%22type%22%3A%20%22string%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22start_dt%22%3A%20%7B%22type%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20%22format%22%3A%20%22date%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22end_dt%22%3A%20%7B%22type%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20%22format%22%3A%20%22date%22%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22oneOf%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%22required%22%3A%20%5B%22start_dt%22%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%22required%22%3A%20%5B%22end_dt%22%5D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%7D)
- [OK](http://geraintluff.github.io/tv4/try/#?data=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22end_dt%22%3A%20%222012-10-10%22%0A%7D&schema=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22object%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22properties%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%7B%22type%22%3A%20%22string%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22start_dt%22%3A%20%7B%22type%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20%22format%22%3A%20%22date%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22end_dt%22%3A%20%7B%22type%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20%22format%22%3A%20%22date%22%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22oneOf%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%22required%22%3A%20%5B%22start_dt%22%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%22required%22%3A%20%5B%22end_dt%22%5D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%7D)
- [NOT OK](http://geraintluff.github.io/tv4/try/#?data=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22start_dt%22%3A%20%222012-10-10%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22end_dt%22%3A%20%222013-11-11%22%0A%7D&schema=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22object%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22properties%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%7B%22type%22%3A%20%22string%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22start_dt%22%3A%20%7B%22type%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20%22format%22%3A%20%22date%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22end_dt%22%3A%20%7B%22type%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20%22format%22%3A%20%22date%22%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22oneOf%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%22required%22%3A%20%5B%22start_dt%22%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%22required%22%3A%20%5B%22end_dt%22%5D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%7D)

Comment: cloudfeet: Thanks for the info. I must've missed that in reading the docs. Learned something new today

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot for that clarification! IMO the section about oneOf / allOf in the JSON schema specification is not very clear, maybe it needs more examples such as this one here