# JSON schema: How to define that some combinations of properties are mandatory

Tags: json, jsonschema

For example there are 2 json propertries X and Y, each of them is optional but one of them must be presented either X or Y. How to define such json schema?

Answer (score 1):

You can use oneOf to specify your possible combinations of required properties. See also [How to make json-schema to allow one but not another field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436589/how-to-make-json-schema-to-allow-one-but-not-another-field)

```
"oneOf": [
  { 
    "properties": {
      "A": {"$ref": "aType"},
      "B": {"$ref": "bType"},          
      "X": {"$ref": "xType"}
    }      
    "required": ["A", "B", "X" ],
    "additionalProperties": false
  },
  { 
    "properties": {
      "A": {"$ref": "aType"},
      "B": {"$ref": "bType"},          
      "Y": {"$ref": "yType"}
    }      
    "required": ["A", "B", "Y" ],
    "additionalProperties": false
  }
]
```